# counting values in embedded ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, count

Quick fire question.

If I have a list of values and I wan't to find the total and display it in embedded ruby, how would I go about this.

```
<% @user.recipes.each do |i| %>
  <% i.awards.each do |k| %>
    <%= k.points %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This renders:

```
1 10 5 5 10 1 5 10 5 1
```

with each number (1, 5 or 10) being a value from the database. Is there any  way to get a count of this? Or would it be better to create a seperate method in the controller to work this out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<%= i.awards.sum(:points) %>
```

For for the sum of all points from all recipes:

```
<%= @user.recipes.map { |r| r.awards.sum(:points) }.sum %>
```

Although it might be sensible to do this calculation within the model. You'll remove a lot of duplication that way if you use it in more than one view.

UPDATE:

As per the comments below, you could also ask the DB to calculate the sum for you:

```
<%= @user.recipes.joins(:awards).sum('awards.points') %>
```

Comment: Absolute hero. Than you so much, thats just what i needed! This way should be fine for now. If I need to do it in the model I might change it later. Would you know how to do this calculation in the model?

Comment: In exactly the same way, just put it in a method in your `User` class, called `total_recipe_points` or something then call `@user.total_recipe_points`

Comment: I'd rather see the sum of all points from all recipes pushed down to the database, I think.

Comment: Something like `@user.recipes.joins(:awards).sum('awards.points')` perhaps?

Comment: Thank you everyone for this feedback. Ill try a few options.

Comment: putting the code in my model results in an undefined method 'recipes'. I guess I just need to define it in the model?

Comment: Is `recipes` not a relation between a `User` model and a `Recipe` model? If `@user.recipes` triggers an error then your example code was also broken in the same way.